# Drupal html files under sites/default/files/* is downloading but executing

Tags: apache, http, drupal, drupal-7

Drupal html files under `sites/default/files/*` is downloading but executing.

Note: `.htaccess` file under `sites/default/files/` is with default setting as below:

## Turn off all options we don't need.

```
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

## Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.

```
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>
```

## If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why do you have html files there? It's directory for files uploaded by admin, usually images, pdf's and similar. Having html files there is not so common.

Comment: I'm using https://www.opigno.org/en module, which has its scorm packages under files directory(sites/default/files/opigno_scorm_extracted)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after adding a .htaccess file with below

ForceType text/html
        Header set Content-Disposition inline